# How to read from text file and show it as a dropdown (select) in html

Tags: javascript, python, flask, text

I have a text file stored in my local which contains the list of usernames that i want to show as a drop down in html page. I need to know how to go about doing this also any piece of code or push in the right direction would be appreciated? P.S I am very new to coding !!

I have already tried loading text files to display as html using the below code

```
var openFile = function(event) {
var input = event.target;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
  var text = reader.result;
  var node = document.getElementById('output');
  node.innerText = text;
  console.log(reader.result.substring(0, 200));
};
reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

But this does not serve my purpose.
I would like a dropdown the options of which are populated from a text file.

Comment: Do you want to do this in `PHP`, `python` or `javascript`?

Comment: python or javascript will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide the text file structure. So I don't know how is it. But according to your information, the simplest solution is to use,

**HttpRequest**

You can read about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) also.

```
function readFile(fileName)
{
    var node = document.getElementById('output');

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", fileName, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(xhttp.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(xhttp.status === 200 || xhttp.status == 0)
            {
                var text = xhttp.responseText;
                node.innerText = text;
            }
        }
    }

    xhttp.send();
}
```

And specify `file://` in your filename when using an absolute path,

```
readFile("file:///Drive/and/your/path/to/file.ext");
```

This is to give you an idea. Hope this helps you.